# How can I display child of one element above its sibling?

Tags: html, css

There are two divs side by side with same zIndex. I want to display a child div of first div over the second div kinda like an overlay. But no matter what zIndex i give to the child div, it remains below the second div.

```css
.parent {
  border: 5px dotted red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.child {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 50px 50px;
  background-color: midnightblue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.child-hover {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 80px;
  top: 0;
  left: 90%;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-hover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

([Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/stellarloony/9L3hde8z/2/))

In this fiddle you'll see two blue squares and a green ellipse. Part of green ellipse is hidden beneath the second blue square. I understand that's because the second div came after the first div in the html. I don't want that to happen.

Edit: I do **not** wish to remove the zIndex from `.child`.

Comment: Is changing the `z-index` of the first `.child` an option?

Comment: @DBS nope that's not an option

Comment: Is changing the order of the element in the DOM an option? (Keeping them in the same position visually)

Comment: @DBS well, I'm creating these divs by javascript and number of these divs is not pre defined, so even if i change the order, it will cause issue.

Comment: read the duplicate until the end and you will find a few tricks with 3D transform

Answer (score 2):

> Remove .child class z-index

```css
 .parent {
            border: 5px dotted red;
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            display:flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: start;
            padding: 50px;
            background-color: black;
        }
        .child {
            border: 5px solid blue;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 0 0 50px 50px;
            background-color: midnightblue;
            position: relative;
        }

        .child-hover {
            position: absolute;
            border: 3px solid green;
            border-radius: 40px;
            height: 60px;
            width: 80px;
            top: 0;
            left: 90%;
            background-color: green;
            z-index: 9999 !important;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dropdown</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <div class="child-hover">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is modifying the zIndex too

Comment: Yes 
.parent .child:nth-child(1){z-index:99;}

Comment: I am hoping for a solution that does not modify the zIndex.

Comment: okk then dont need to add first child style remove child z-index 10

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is remove the z-index in the .child class. Please try this.

```css
.parent {
  border: 5px dotted red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.child {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 50px 50px;
  background-color: midnightblue;
  position: relative;

}

.child-hover {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 80px;
  top: 0;
  left: 90%;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-hover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index works with the positioned elements on the same level.
Try adding this to your CSS code.

```css
.child:first-of-type {
  z-index: 11;
}
```